# Pandas: Is there a more performatic method to join few columns of other Dataframe than merge()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, etl

I have a situation where I need to get 2 columns of another Dataframe and join them in the first Dataframe, based on a filter like a Foreign Key.

```
Frame1
column1     column2    column3 ........ column98      column99
1           7          15               John          7          
2           9          32               Dale          4
3           4          25               Leon          2  

Frame2      
columnA    columnB    columnC      columnD    columnE           
1          Leon       24           13         6
1          Nicolas    19           12         4
1          Albert     32           34         9
1          Dale       14           42         2
1          John       18           33         1


Result
column1     column2    column3 ........ column98      column99   columnD   columnE
1           7          15               John          7          33        1      
2           9          32               Dale          4          42        2
3           4          25               Leon          2          13        6
```

I am doing that to get this result:

```
Frame1 = Frame1.merge(Frame2[['columnB','columnD', 'columnE']], left_on = 'column98', right_on ='columnB', how='left' )
```

My doubt is because I see other methods to get columns in others DataFrames, like lookup, melt, loc, and my DataFrame1 have million of rows, so I am looking for the most performatic way of doing this.

Best Regards,
Luis

Comment: merges are pretty performant AFAIK and a very general solution. If you're in some special cases, like a join on one column that you expect to be M:1 (or 1:1) then you _can_ `map` to get an identical output as a `left` merge.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of DataFrame indexes to have high performance merges. There's some performance differences depending on whether you have unqiue keys.

```py
Frame1.set_index('column98', inplace=True)
Frame1.sort_index(inplace=True)

Frame2.set_index('columnB', inplace=True)
Frame.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: If I put this index, I will need to change something in my merge() method or will the method, signature and parameters be the same?

Comment: If the index has the same name in both DataFrames then you don't need to specify any merge parameters iirc. In your particular case where the indexes have different names you can specify left_index=True, right_index=True. I'm not 100% what happens if you leave ```left_on=``` and ```right_on=``` as they are. The documents seem to suggest that it can be an index name but my intuition says otherwise